# UNIX Copy/Move files in same directory preserving timestamp

Tags: unix, file-permissions, timestamp, cp, mv

Following is the scenario. There are multiple files in a directory created by users belonging to same unix group.

Unix Group: Prod.
User in Prod Unix Group: User1 User2 User3.

All 3 users have same privileges.

Scenario 1
If user3 wants to become owner of the files created by user1 and user2 by preserving datetime stamp  what is the command user3 needs to execute?

Scenario 2
Can user copy/move the same file in same directory by preserving datetimestamp? What is the command for it?

Scenario3:
I tried touch command for the file created by User1. Ownership is changed however timestamp is updated too. Is there a way that timestamp remains the same using touch command?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Only root can change ownership of files, so user3 will need to be able to use `sudo` to change ownership of files belonging to user1 and user2.

`mv` will always preserve all metadata, including modification time and user and group ownership. `cp -p` will try to preserve all these, but as stated above you can't create files with owner other than yourself, so user and group ownership of files copied with `cp -p` won't be preserved if you're not already the owner.

`touch` is designed to change the modification time. I do not see how using `touch` can change the ownership, I would like to see steps how to reproduce what you saw. However you can use `touch --reference=filename filename` to preserve the modification time, but it would be useless as it would actually not do anything.